# Elasticsearch script to query hostnames

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am looking to create a script that will query multiple hostnames and provide a not found result if it is not in the index and provide the host and count of documents on the server if it is found.  What I have so far seems to work, but I am unsure of how to make it query multiple servers and provide the correct result.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
GET /index1*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-7d",
              "lt": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "host.name": "server1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "hosts": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 1000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "hostname": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "host.name"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great start so far! You can simply change the `term` query into a `terms` one. Also, you need to leverage the [missing bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_missing_bucket) feature for the not found result:

```
GET /index1*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-7d",
              "lt": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "host.name": ["server1", "server2", "server3"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "hosts": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 1000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "hostname": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "host.name",
                "missing_bucket": true,
                "missing_order": "last"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

All the servers which have documents during the given time interval will have buckets, all the others will be in the "null" bucket.